# continuity problem

Tags: calculus

[image: the question !!]
how to answer the question in the image in steps as all I know is that the denominator has no real zeroes but i don't know what to do next !!!!

Comment: I think they just want you to find all $a$ so that $x^2-ax+25\not=0$ $\forall$ $x$

Comment: but how to reach the answer on the right ??

Answer (score 1):

By the quadratic formula, the solutions to $x^2-ax+25=0$ are $\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-100}}{2}$.  This has no real solutions as long as $a^2-100<0$.  Thus $a^2<100$.  Or equivalently $-10<a<10$.